# Lowest Common Multiple of polynomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gcd-and-lcm

Find the lowest common multiple of:

$3x^3-7x^2y+5xy^2-y^3$

$x^2y+3xy^2-3x^3-y^3$

$3x^3+5x^2y+xy^2-y^3$

I look at the second expression, and can immediately simplify it to: $3x(y^2-x^2)-y(y^2-x^2) \rightarrow (3x-y)(y^2-x^2) \rightarrow (3x-y)(y+x)(y-x)$

I realize the first and third expressions are divisible by $(3x-y)$, hence the three expressions become:

$(x^2-2xy+y^2)(3x-y) \rightarrow (x-y)^2(3x-y)$

$(3x-y)(y+x)(y-x)$

$(x^2+2xy+y^2)(3x-y) \rightarrow (x+y)^2(3x-y)$

Then by inspection the Lowest Common Multiple should be $(3x-y)(x+y)^2(x-y)^2(y-x)$

But the textbook gives the answer as $(3x-y)(x+y)^2(x-y)^2$

I feel it's a typo by forgetting $(y-x)$ but I'm not sure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your title mentions HCF but you say LCM in the body. Which is it?

Comment: Ignore the sign on $x-y.$ For all three polys, the $x-y$ part divides $(x-y)^2.$ So no need of another factor of $x-y$ in the LCM.

Comment: But why can the sign be ignored? $(x-y)=(-1)(y-x)$, so shouldn't the answer then be $(3x-y)(x+y)^2(x-y)^2(-1)$? Thanks.

Comment: In the ring of polynomials in $x,y$ over the integers, the constant polynomial $(-1)$ is a unit [= divisor of $1$]. And LCM's are not unique, only unique up to a unit factor.

Comment: $$(x-y) (3 x-y) (x+y)^2 \left(3 x^3-x^2 y^2+5 x y^2-y^3\right)$$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Where does the last factor of your comment come from? The three polys whose LCM is sought are all homogeneous of total degree $3$ in $x,y.$ Your extra factor is not, and I don't see any factors of the three given polys which are factors of your extra factor.